# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' and also not looping

Tags: python, html, list, for-loop, web-scraping

Trying to scrape a page but its not looping and by extracting data from the other items and aslo i just want the text but it shows

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

i am confused

this is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer
url = "https://www.jumia.com.ng/computing/"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('a', class_="core")


for lista in lists:
    laptop_name = lista.find('h3', class_="name").text
    price = lista.find('div', class_="old").text
    best_price = lista.find('div', class_="prc").test
    percentage_discount = lista.find('div', class_="bdg_dsct_sm").test

info = [laptop_name, price, best_price, percentage_discount]
print(info)
```

```
[<h3 class="name">Hp 15 Intel Celeron N4020 8GB RAM 1TB HDD Windows 10 + Mouse</h3>, <div class="old">₦ 235,000</div>, <div class="prc">₦ 199,000</div>, None]
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16528/2657122307.py in <module>
      1 for lista in lists:
----> 2     laptop_name = lista.find('h3', class_="name").text
      3     price = lista.find('div', class_="old").text
      4     best_price = lista.find('div', class_="prc").test
      5     percentage_discount = lista.find('div', class_="bdg_dsct_sm").test

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: It means `.find` didn't find any `"h3"`s with the class `"name"`.

Comment: Per BeautifulSoup documentation find(...) doesn't have a property, text,   soup.find('title')
# <title>The Dormouse's story</title>,  doc  here,  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find

Answer (score 0):

To get name, price, discount of the products on that page you can try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.jumia.com.ng/computing/"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for article in soup.select("article.prd"):
    laptop_name = article.find(class_="name").text
    price = article.find("div", class_="prc").get("data-oprc")
    best_price = article.find("div", class_="prc").text

    percentage_discount = article.find("div", class_="_dsct")
    percentage_discount = (
        percentage_discount.text if percentage_discount else "N/A"
    )

    info = [laptop_name, price, best_price, percentage_discount]
    all_data.append(info)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Name", "Price 1", "Price 2", "Discount"])
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Name | Price 1 | Price 2 | Discount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Speedisk 3.0 Pen Flash Drive 64GB - Metal With Micro USB OTG | ₦ 10,000 | ₦ 2,699 | 73% |
| Lenovo V15-IGL Intel Celeron 1TB HDD 4GB RAM Win 10 | ₦ 160,990 | ₦ 130,990 | 19% |
| Hp 15 Intel Celeron N4020 8GB RAM 1TB HDD Windows 10 + Mouse | ₦ 235,000 | ₦ 199,000 | 15% |
| Asus E203NAH Intel Celeron 4GB RAM 128GB EMMC 11.6' Win 10 - Star Grey | ₦ 119,990 | ₦ 99,990 | 17% |
| Lenovo AMD RYZEN 3 1TB HDD 8GB RAM 2.6 To 3.4ghz Win 10+ 32GB Flash | ₦ 250,000 | ₦ 218,500 | 13% |